# New build PC with display issue, sometimes load but most times it doesn't when powering up

Tags: computer-building, desktop-computer

I have an issue with a system I've built recently. It was going fine for a month or so. Recently the display has been on and off. I haven't added any new components.

My PC powers up with every fans spinning, sometimes the bios doesn't load, I get the standard dark screen with monitor on. Sometimes it loads and works as normal. Every fan is spinning and working from CPU, GPU and secondary fans.

I've tried a few recommended solutions to diagnose the actual problem:

1. Remove CMOS battery and leave it out for 5+ minutes and putting it back in.
2. I've also removed each component one by one and putting them back in.

   - took out the RAM, I get the POST Beeps to indicate no RAMS installed. So I put that back in.
   - took out the graphics card and try powering it up. (Surprisingly no beep at all).
   - removed other PCI cards and try again.
3. Detached other power cables and switched them around to see if any are faulty.
4. I've ensured all other cables are tightly plugged in and secured.

**My PC setup:**

1. Asus M5 A97 R2.0
2. HyperX DDR3 16 GB
3. Asus Radeon R7 360 OC 2GB GDDR5 2xDVI HDMI DisplayPort
4. AMD Piledriver FX-6300 AM3+ 3.5GHz Hexacore
5. Graphics card is using HDMI -> TV. (I've also tried another PC monitor).
6. FSP Raider Edition 750W 80PLUS Silver Power
7. Asus DRW-24D3ST 24x Black Sata DVD Writer OEM.
8. OS - Windows 10 (upgraded from Win 7 Ultimate).

Any other recommendation. I don't think the motherboard is bust, otherwise it wouldn't load sometimes and not others. Currently its working but if I turn it off, it may sometimes take up to 10 or 20 + times before I can boot back into my OS after multiple resets or power off.

Comment: Please include your power supply make/model. Do you have access to any other parts you can try (particularly, a spare power supply, but potentially a different graphics card)? TVs can be kind of finicky sometimes, maybe try a standard monitor and see if it changes anything? What drives do you have installed? Dodgy hard drives can sometimes cause weird stability issues.

Comment: @Ash, I've updated the details, I also added that I've tried a PC monitor as well. Forgot to mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Tried swapping known good video, ram & power supply? Intermittent errors with only the motherboard+video+ram+power plugged in, after swapping video cards & ram & power, sure sounds like a failing motherboard. Checked input power too, wall voltage, ground, using a UPS that maybe drops from 120V to 75V (had 2 completely different manufacturer's UPS's that did that for about 20s, 30s after being turned on: enough time for a computer to start booting, then get hit with a big voltage drop)?

Comment: Someone might be able to answer exactly, but unfortunately it sounds like one of those things where it becomes a process of elimination. It could still be the motherboard (don't discount that possibility, but it's one of the hardest problems to diagnose; check for bulging capacitors or any other obvious damage), it could be temps, it could be faulty cables, it could be the other things @Xen and I mentioned. Your power supply isn't too bad, but my first guess would be that, based on the symptoms.

Comment: @Xen2050, Ash - Thanks guys, I'll keep going and see how far I get. Its just frustrating when you've just had it for 1-2 months working properly and suddenly gone wacko. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

After much headache from isolation testing, I ended up going back to the shop and use the warranty on the part, swapped the motherboard for a brand new one.

It seems like its working again, something must have went nuts with the old board after 1-2 months of usage.

Hopefully this one last longer than the last.